# Working with python dictionary and Lambda functions

Tags: python

This is my code to write a simple qr code generator with options. How do I run the send function only when the correct option is chosen? I'm not calling the send function unless it is called when assigned? If so, how can I get the dictionary to contain the value I need but not call it?

```
// imports

import sys
import os
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

// api-endpoint
URL = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code"
data = "Example Text"
size = "200x200"
color = "0-0-0"  # black
bgcolor = "255-255-255"  # white

# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
PARAMS = {'data': data, 'size': size, 'color': color, 'bgcolor': bgcolor}

check = False
while(not check):
    print("Welcome to my QR code generator")
    print("--------------------------------")
    print("Press 1 to add data (Default: \"Example Text\"")
    print("Press 2 to change size (Default: 200x200)")
    print("press 3 to change color (Default: 0-0-0 <-- Black)")
    print("Press 4 to change background color (Default: 255-255-255 <-- White)")
    print("Press 5 to show your selected options")
    print("Press c to create QR code")
    print("Press q to exit")


def Send(x):
    # sending get request and saving the response as response object
    r = requests.get(url=URL, params=x)
    r.content
    i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
    i.show()
def CleanupAndQuit():
    exit()

menuchoices = {'1': AddData, '2': ChangeSize, '3': ChangeColor,
               '4': ChangeBGColor, '5': ShowAll, 'c': Send(PARAMS), 'q': CleanupAndQuit}
ret = menuchoices[input()]()
if ret is None:
    print("Please enter a choice")
```

Comment: What do you mean by it not being called? You are calling it where you assign `menuchoices`

Comment: `if ret == 'c': Send(PARAMS)`?

Comment: Nathaniel Todd-Long, do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of `menuchoices` you are immediately calling the function `Send` with `PARAMS`.

What you might try instead is using [lambda expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp):

```
menuchoices = {
   'c': lambda: Send(PARAMS)
}
```

This way you avoid immediate call to `Send` and keep it configured for lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

In the `menuchoices` dictionary, you are calling the function Send.

Comment: I suggest you initialize the dictionary with 'c' : None and then, if 'c' is chosen, substitute None with Send(PARAMS)